# Macro to define in which order some text appears

Tags: macros

I have several piece of text for which I would like to be able to change easily the order in which they appear. Is there a way to do that?

The only solution I found until now is the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\firsttext}{blabla 1}
\newcommand{\secondtext}{$$blabla 2$$}
\newcommand{\thirdtext}{{\Large blabla 3}}  
\begin{document}
\firsttext
\secondtext
\thirdtext
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

In this way I can easily change the order of the paragraphs just by switching the call for macros in the document. For example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\firsttext}{blabla 1}
\newcommand{\secondtext}{$$blabla 2$$}
\newcommand{\thirdtext}{{\Large blabla 3}}  
\begin{document}
\secondtext
\thirdtext
\firsttext
\end{document}
```

outputs
[image]

The problem of this method is that the text that can be defined in the `\newcommand{}{}` is very limited. For example, I get an error if I replace
`\newcommand{\secondtext}{$$blabla 2$$}`
by `\newcommand{\secondtext}{ \begin{equation*}blabla 2\end{equation*}}`

However, the text I would like to easily be able to switch contains theorems, equations, etc...

Is there a proper way to do that?

Comment: You need `\usepackage{amsmath}` to use `equation*`, add that and it works.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. said. You get the same error if you use the `equation*` environment normally as part of your document body because it simply isn't defined. `\usepackage{mathtools}` solves the problem.

Comment: :), ok that's great thank you 2. But I have then another problem. If I want to acces the Latex code for an equation from the PDF (rightclick with Texmaker) then it is not possible anymore. So I'm still interested in some better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t) and [@cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) pointed out in the comments, the issue is that a package is missing in order to use the `equation*` environnement.

The problem can be solved by simply adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` or `\usepackage{mathtools}` in the preamble.